# Do all isothermal process require a thermal reservoir?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

Or in another way, that I guess to be equivalent, there is a isothermal process without the presence of a thermal reservatory?

For example in experiences did in our atmosphere that are called isothermal usually the atmosphere itself is the reservoir, at least locally.

Do you have some example of isothermal process without the presence of a thermal reservoir?

Answer (score 1):

Well in an isothermal transformation, since the internal energy change is zero (that is actually true only for an ideal gas), you have heat equal to work ($Q=W$). Thus suppose you are extracting (doing) work from (on) a system, the system will have to adsorb (produce) the same amount of heat if you want the. That heat as somewhere to go so I would say that yes, you need a reservoir of some kind to adsorb/give heat.